# Equivalent for "stringByDeletingPathExtension " for an array

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I want to run `stringByDeletingPathExtension` for all NSString members of an NSArray. How can I do this in Objective-C?

Comment: What do you mean by "equellent"?

Comment: Do you mean to execute this method on each member of an NSArray ? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>`NSArray *myArray = ... ;`</strike>

```
[myArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(stringByDeletingPathExtension)];
```

**EDIT**: As @Wevah pointed out in the comments, this solution does not solve the problem, since stringByDeletingPathExtension returns a string rather than modified the object on which is invoked.

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:myArray] autorelease];
for( int i = 0; i < [newArray count]; i++ ) {
   NSString* oneItem = [newArray objectAtIndex:i];
   [newArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[oneItem stringByDeletingPathExtension]]; 
}
```

then use your newArray ...

Comment: That's not really going to do anything useful, though, since `stringByDeletingPathExtension` returns a new (autoreleased) string…

Comment: NSString* fullPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[destfileName stringByDeletingPathExtension]  ofType:@"xml"];  like this how can do for NSArray? can u please tell me the syntax?

Comment: but i need array elements in which its extentions r trimmed

Comment: @Wevah - hehh, you are absolutely right :) ... i will correct my answer (i was quick on answering, slow on thinking ....)

Comment: Really there should be a `makeObjectsPerformBlock:` method or `map`. Maybe worth raising a bugreport with Apple.